# Updated Document after every update operation in MongoDB using Change Stream

Tags: mongodb, changestream

We are using MongoDB in production and for some use cases, **we have to push updated document from the application after every update operation to Kafka**.
In MongoDB 3.6 new feature called **Change Stream** introduced and 
currently, we are trying to use change stream feature instead of pushing updated document from the application.

But change stream only return the delta of fields during the update operation and also use `full_document='updateLookup'` but this 
return the most current majority-committed version document, not for that particular event.

**Is there any approach** (or alternative) **to get the updated document for that particular event like AWS DynamoDB** (for every update operation DynamoDB stream give NewImage)

**For every update event in AWS Dynamodb table**, event contain
**OldImage** (The item in the DynamoDB table as it appeared
before it was modified) and **NewImage**(The item in the DynamoDB table as it appeared after it was modified)

```
{
    ...
    "dynamodb": {
        "OldImage": {
            "Message": {
                "S": "New item!"
            },
            "Id": {
                "N": "101"
            }
        },
        "Keys": {
            "Id": {
            "N": "101"
            }
        },
        "NewImage": {
            "Message": {
                "S": "This item has changed"
            },
            "Id": {
                "N": "101"
            }
        }
    },
    ...
}
```

But in case of MongoDB Change Stream when pass `full_document='updateLookup'`  as an option will return **most current majority-committed version of the updated document**

See https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/changeStreams/#lookup-full-document-for-update-operations

Comment: I'm unclear about your requirement. Can you elaborate with an example of what NewImage does vs. the output of `updateLookup`?

Comment: @KevinAdistambhaI updated question with sample Dynamodb stream event

Comment: As far as I'm aware, there is no `OldImage` functionality related to MongoDB changestream. `updateLookup` is probably the closest, but as you observed, this will return majority-committed version of the document, which is similar but I don't believe exactly duplicates the `NewImage` functionality. You might be able to simulate this by using majority write concern and `updateLookup`, of which it should return after the majority write was successful (which implies it is the majority-committed document).